# Message "Spurious thread death event" in gdb

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb

I am running a C++ multi-threaded linux application in gdb. I get error message "Spurious thread death event". I  couldn't find why this message comes. 
In non-gdb run, I don't see any issue with the run or crash. So I cannot know if this is 'real' issue with application or some issue related to debugging in gdb. Any information regarding this message will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that this is quite interesting. It seems that gdb keeps track of threads as they are created and destroyed. In this case gdb notices that a thread was destroyed without being aware of the same thread being created. There is a nice article here: http://timetobleed.com/how-do-debuggers-keep-track-of-the-threads-in-your-program/
As far as I see this is an error of the "this should never happen" kind, meaning that this might be a bug in gdb / libthread_db... Could you provide a minimal example that triggers the behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for the info. The issue observed is random. In my application, there are many points in the flow where threads are created and destroyed.  In different runs, this message come at different points in gdb. Due to randomness, it difficult to give an example. This message comes even if I don't give any breakpoint and 'run' till the end.